# Some subclasses seem deliberately missing from the SSN ontology RDF. Is there a way to import a complete SSN ontology?

Tags: ontology, protege

I am using `Protege` to explore the SSN ontology,
but a lot of classes like the [survivalRange](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-ssn/#SSNSYSTEMSurvivalRange) seem to be missing from [the main file](https://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/).

How could I import all the classes and entities of the `ssn-system`,
without importing them manually one by one by the IRI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/systems/`, which itself imports `http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/`.